# Syncadapter performSync is not working in queue if Network from offline to online for Android 7 and above

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat, android-syncadapter, android-7.1-nougat

performSync() is working in order for Android below 7. The same is not working in order (Queue) for Android 7 and above.

The sync adapter configuration is as below.

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="@string/account_type"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:contentAuthority="@string/authority"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
    android:supportsUploading="true"
    android:userVisible="false" />
```

The authenticator.xml is as below

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="@string/account_type"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/label"
    android:smallIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

The code using for manual sync is as below.

```
private void requestSync(Account account, PersonDto personDto) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true); // Performing a sync no matter if it's off
            bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true); // Performing a sync no matter if it's off
            bundle.putString("SYNC_TYPE", "SendPerson");
            ContentResolver.requestSync(account, ReferenceCodeContentProvider.AUTHORITY, bundle);
}
```

The ApplicationSyncAdapter code is as below

```
    public class ApplicationSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

        private static final String TAG = "ApplicationSyncAdapter";

        private final AccountManager mAccountManager;

        public ApplicationSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
            super(context, autoInitialize);
            mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
        }

            @Override
            public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
                                      ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
         String syncType = extras.getString("SYNC_TYPE");
 if (syncType.equals("SendPerson")) {
}
        }
```

I am calling requestSync() method in a loop of 5 persons in offline (no network)
It's working fine for android below 7. i.e when the network comes back. the performSync() is calling in order which I gave in order (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)

But for Android 7 and above, the order in which I gave in for loop is not the same order in performSync() method. i.e, performSync() method is calling random order. (p3, p2, p4, p1, p5)

Is there any problem with my code?